# can i use the google map api to get the map and make changes to it?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, api

I need to make an app to show the available bus routes inside the 1 km range of a person. can I do that inside google map with the google map API?
 Or if I could would that bring any legal actions against me?

Comment: You can do. There won't be any problem. :)

Comment: with just the normal google maps API ?

Comment: Yes..There is limit for hit count if you are using direction api..